# Statements about density of states and dimensionality

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In quantum mechanics density of states $g(E)$ describes how dense the energy levels are around the energy $E$. In other words $g(E) dE$ is the number of levels in the energy interval $E$ to $E + dE$.

Are there general statements if the density of states either decreases, remains constant or increases with energy in the thermodynamic limit ($L \rightarrow \infty$)? In other words are the energy levels more separated at higher energy, equally spaced or closer to each other?

**Hypothesis** The homogeneous box with infinite walls gives a lower bound for $g(E)$. Other confining potentials can only increase the density of states ($g(E) \geq g_{box}(E)$ for all $E$).

**Idea** Other potentials can only by less confining at higher energies than the box. Else the potential gets larger at the center and is anti-confining. If the potential opens more towards higher energies the levels move closer to each other and lead to a higher density of states.

**Box potential in different dimensions**
Density of states $g(E)$ is zero below the potential minimum. Above it behaves as follows:

- 3D box: $g(E) \sim \sqrt{E}$
- 2D box: $g(E) \sim const$
- 1D box: $g(E) \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{E}}$

Together with the hypothesis this would mean that in 3D all density of states are increasing, in 2D constant or increasing and in 1D no general statement is possible. At least this is true if the density of states are monotonic.

Is this reasoning true? Is it possible to make general statements about specific potential shapes, e.g. power law potentials $V(x) = \sum_{i=1}^d a_i x_i^\gamma$ with some power $\gamma$ and dimension $d$ or gaussian potentials? Or for certain classes of potentials such as potentials with a single minimum to exclude periodic lattices? Density of states of lattices are not monotonic due to band gaps.

**Example harmonic potential**
For a harmonic potential the reasoning seems to be valid. Density of states $g(E)$ is zero below the potential minimum. Above it behaves as follows:

- 1D harmonic oscillator: $g(E) \sim const$
- 2D harmonic oscillator: $g(E) \sim E$
- 3D harmonic oscillator: $g(E) \sim E^2$

It seems that most density of states are of the form $g(E) = a E^b$ with coefficients $a$ and $b$ that depend on the potential shape and the dimension. When is this true?

Comment: Does anybody have an idea? Partial answers are welcome as well.